# Seeing uploaded images in views

Tags: image, drupal-6, drupal-views

using drupal 6.
Modules installed for working with the images:

- filefield
- image
- imageapi
- imagefield
- imagecache

I made this content type called 'event' where I added the possibility to upload an image.

The preview shows that I successfully filtered the nodes according to type showing the node type and node body just fine.
When I click the '+' next to fields, I'm being given a couple of options about images and the first one seems to be what I'm looking for; image:image. 
When I visit the nodes seperately by inserting their path into the address bar, I see the title with the body and the original image below it. 
But no matter what I seem to do in views, the list of events won't show any of the images that are part of the nodes. Not even when I set 'image size to show' to orignal.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out eventually. First, it needed to be an image that is part of the 'content' category under 'fields'. Then I set a thumbnail which I could then select from a dropdown once I've chosen 'content: image'.

Now, something that has to do with the permissions has me floundring again. So that's for a  [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398547/drupal-views-image-permissions) I guess.